# Sculpting with Dyntopo and mirroring

Tags: sculpting, mirror

I'm having a major issue with creating the Ogre creature in a Blender Course. I created the arms, legs, torso and head. Added subdivision and mirror modifers to all to create the arms and legs on the other side of the torso. When I click on Dyntopo, it gives me a warning message, I click ok and one of my legs disappears and the visible one is polygonized. So instead of rounded, it's back to an asymmetric polygon. I can't seem to figure this out. Pleas help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I would *apply* the modifiers first. Hover the mouse over the modifier and press Ctrl+A or use *Apply* from the dropdown menu right next to the modifier's name. The modifier on the top should be applied first.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried to apply and all it did was make the existing mirror modifier disappear.

Comment: You shouldn't wonder that after enabling _Dyntopo_ it makes your subdivision and mirrored geometry disappear. You might ignore the warning message, but at least it's a hint there could be a problem with modifiers... after enabling _Dyntopo_ your _Subdivision Surface_ and _Mirror_ modifier both should display a warning, too: "Not supported in dyntopo". And because they are not suported they don't affect the mesh anymore.

Comment: But by the way, after you leave _Sculpt Mode_ and go back to _Object Mode_ the modifiers will work again. It's just that dyntopo is a destructive method which is actually changing the mesh, whereas the modifiers are non-destructive as long as they are not applied. Dyntopo cannot work with a procedural mesh as it needs real geometry to sculpt and remesh. Also the general _Sculpt Mode_ doesn't sculpt the subdivided mesh as long as the modifier is not applied. It just don't give a warning because it works with the existing geometry before subdivision, it doesn't have to generate new vertices.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.